# How do I transpose this data frame to look like the following example (long to wide)?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, transpose, spread

I have this data table that showcases customer service agent IDs and behaviors that the agents were coached on by a quality coach who listens to the call. I want to transpose this data frame: [long data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSMj7.png)

To look like this: [wide data (goal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUhG9.png)

Basically, I want to see for an agent ID, in horizontal chronological coaching date, is this agent improving or not, which is evident by the strategy as time goes along.

Is this possible?

Comment: PLEASE provide dummy data not images to make more reproducible your example and help you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible using the `pivot_wider` function from the library `tidyr`.
You can refer this link for its documentation : https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html

It would be easy to provide actual code to do this once you share a reproducible example of your dataframe instead of the images.